# Android pending intent not being called within widget

Tags: android, android-widget, speech-recognition, android-pendingintent

Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530472/widget-that-calls-speech-recognition-app) question (accepted answer), I'm trying to launch voice recognition from one of my app's widgets. I succesfully managed to open dialog that requests voice input with this code inside `onUpdate()` method of the Widget:

```
    // this intent points to activity that should handle results, doesn't work
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(SoulissApp.getAppContext(), WrapperActivity.class );
    //doesn't work as well
    //activityIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("it.angelic.soulissclient", "it.angelic.soulissclient.WrapperActivity"));
    // this intent wraps results activity intent
    PendingIntent resultsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SoulissApp.getAppContext(), 0, activityIntent, 0);

    // this intent calls the speech recognition
    Intent voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    voiceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT, resultsPendingIntent);

    Bundle fakeBun = new Bundle();
    fakeBun.putChar("fake", 'f');
    voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT_BUNDLE, fakeBun);

    // this intent wraps voice recognition intent, works
    PendingIntent pendingInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, voiceIntent, 0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingInt);
```

The speech recognition works, but **at the end of the recognition process, my `resultsPendingIntent` is not called. Why?**

From sys log, I read this:

```
 ...I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=it.angelic.soulissclient/.SoulissWidgetVoice (has extras)} from uid 10152 on display 0......
```

while I'd expect something like:

```
  ...I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=it.angelic.soulissclient/.WrapperActivity(has extras)}...
```

because `.WrapperActivity` is pending Intent while `SoulissWidgetVoice` is the widget class. Note that `WrapperActivity` itself can be correctly launched from other activities and it's a `Theme.NoDisplay` basic activity:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".WrapperActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide the complete class name with its package prefix as second argument for the ComponentName constructor. First argument is the app 's package name (which can be different from the internal Java package but usually is not).

Comment: thank you @BladeCoder i updated the code but still don't work

Comment: Is your widget a collection widget (ListView, StackView)?

Answer (score 0):

This is fully functional, and it's based off the ListView in the Android SDK. It's not particularly for a widget, but I'm sure you can modify it so that it works for a widget.

Create an activity called SearchActivity:

```
// CustomSearch (View) & ISearch (Interface) are objects that I created and are irrelevant
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ISearch
{
    // Variables
    private CustomSearch mSearchView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        mSearchView = (CustomSearch)findViewById(R.id.search);
        mSearchView.setPendingComponentName(getComponentName());
        mSearchView.setSearchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.i("SEARCH >", "You said: " + query);
        }
    }
}
```

Add activity to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In your custom Widget/View:

```
buttonVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Get activity from either SearchableInfo or ComponentName
        ComponentName searchActivity = mComponentName;

        // Wrap component in intent
        Intent queryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
        queryIntent.setComponent(searchActivity);

        // Wrap query intent in pending intent
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, queryIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        // Create bundle now because if we wrap it in pending intent, it becomes immutable
        Bundle queryExtras = new Bundle();

        // Create voice intent
        Intent voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZER_SPEECH);
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak");
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, searchActivity
        voiceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Wrap the pending intent & bundle inside the voice intent
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT, pending);
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT_BUNDLE, queryExtras);

        // Start the voice search
        getContext().startActivity(voiceIntent);
    }
}
```